# PHP unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, dynamic

I'm trying to install libinjection from **[here](https://github.com/client9)**
I'm trying to install the PHP module but I'm getting this error after `make`, `make install`, `make test`:

> 2/libinjection.so - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/libinjection.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line
>   0 PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant LIBINJECTION_VERSION -
>   assumed 'LIBINJECTION_VERSION' in
>   /home/mohammed/libinjection/php/example.php on line 6
>
> ```
> Using libinjection LIBINJECTION_VERSION PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function new_libinjection_sqli_state() in
> ```
>
> /home/mohammed/libinjection/php/example.php on line 9

In php.ini I added 
    `extension=libinjection.so` but I'm still getting the error.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message

> /usr/lib/php5/20121212/libinjection.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

When you ran `make install` it did not install the extension to the path where PHP is looking for it.

Find where it installed the extension to, and copy `libinjection.so` to `/usr/lib/php5/20121212` and then restart the web server (Apache, nginx etc) and try running your code again.

Comment: I think he didn't build that file, libinjection.so does not exist yet. Btw, you need to reload PHP, not the webserver. The webserver only needs to be restarted when PHP is inbuilt or a module.

Answer (score 0):

To build an extension in PHP,
you first need to run `scripts/phpize` in the PHP folder,

and `./configure` with a prefix to find the correct folder.

Simply using `./configure && make && make install` is **not enough**.

```
chmod +x /usr/local/src/php-5.6.9/scripts/phpize
/usr/local/src/php-5.6.9/scripts/phpize

./configure --prefix /usr/local/src/php-5.6.9 \
--with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
```

Use `./configure --help` to get available options.